# What is anchor-based and anchor free two detection paradigm in object detection?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.08069.pdf) and saw this passage:

> The architecture of these detectors has evolved from the initial two-stage [9, 26, 3] to one stage [19, 31, 1, 10, 22, 13, 36, 14, 7, 33, 11], and two detection paradigms, anchor-based [19, 22, 13, 10, 33] and anchor-free [31, 7, 36, 14, 11], have emerged.

What is meant by anchor-based and anchor free two detection paradigm?